# Virtualbox virtual machine terminates at startup with exit code 1

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox

The following error comes when I start a Machine.

[image: This error comes after Starting a Machine]

The `VBoxStartup.log` contains this entries.

```
f0c.10d8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessWvtTodos: 0 (was 0) fWinVerifyTrust=1 for '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'
f0c.10d8: Fatal error:
f0c.10d8: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: LoadLibrary "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VirtualBox.dll" failed, rc=1790
79c.fac: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[2]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 2239 ms, the end);
534.1200: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 2653 ms, the end);
```

This occurred after windows update. I'm running version *4.3.30 r101610* which I updated recently. The problem exists in previous two releases also (tested).

Answer (score 7):

Go to explorer, right-click `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv\VBoxDrv.inf` and select `Install`

This will reinstall the VirtualBox kernel driver. After that VMs should once again start as expected.

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Comment: Restarting windows fixed it for me

Comment: didn't work for me .

Comment: I did uninstall virtual box. Shutdown Windows. Started Windows. Installed VB. Disabled anti-virus temporarily. It worked.

Comment: It worked. I restarted the host machine and then VM bootup as expected. Thanks a lot.